App calculadora
Estoy intentando hacer una calculadora y necesito que no permita pulsar dos operadores seguidos, ejemplos (54++30, 30--20), no se que puedo usar para conseguir eso, tienen alguna idea?
// NUMEROS
btnNumber.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const activeBtn = e.target;
    display.innerText += `${activeBtn.innerText}`;
  });
});

// OPERACIONES
btnOperacion.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const activeBtn = e.target;
    display.innerText += `${activeBtn.innerText}`;
  });
});


Puedes llevar una bandera en una variable booleana que te indique si el último botón presionado fue un operador. Si lo fue, no aceptas más operadores.
En cada pulsación de un botón numérico, actualizas el valor de esta variable a false y cuando aceptas la pulsación de un botón de operador, la actualizas a true.
let ultimoEsOperador = false;

// NUMEROS
btnNumber.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const activeBtn = e.target;
    display.innerText += `${activeBtn.innerText}`;
    ultimoEsOperador = false;
  });
});

// OPERACIONES
btnOperacion.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (!ultimoEsOperador) {
      const activeBtn = e.target;
      display.innerText += `${activeBtn.innerText}`;
      ultimoEsOperador = true;
    }
  });
});


Buena idea, gracias boss!!
